# What is the exact equivalent of "Matlab besselk(x,y,1)" in c++?

Tags: c++, matlab, boost, bessel-functions

I have tried `boost::math::cyl_bessel_k(x,y) * exp(y)`. In most cases, this is equal to Matlab's scaled `besselk(x,y,1)`. But in some cases (e.g., `x=1`, `y=2000`) when both `besselk(x,y)=0` and `boost::math::cyl_bessel_k(x,y)=0`, Matlab's scaled version `besselk(x,y,1)` gives me different values varies around `10^-3`. But `boost::math::cyl_bessel_k(x,y) * exp(y)` returns `-nan`. I'd like to find an equivalent statement for Matlab's `besselk(x,y,1)`. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not seeing anything in Boost that does what you need (though you might be able to implement it yourself by using lower-level functions). As you've found out, the scaled Bessel functions are not computed simply by multiplying `exp(z)`. The [GSL](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) appears to have incorporated this functionality, e.g., [`gsl_sf_bessel_Knu_scaled`](http://fossies.org/dox/gsl-1.16/bessel__Knu_8c_source.html). For an "exact equivalent," you might look at [the paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=214331) and [code  by Amos](http://octave.sourceforge.net/doxygen/html/dir_9868eb982f7926b88e9e0acf50b9194d.html), e.g., [CBESK](http://octave.sourceforge.net/doxygen/html/d8/d3a/cbesk_8f_source.html). Both Matlab and Octave appear to use this implementation. However, the code is written in Fortran, so you'd need to translate it or put a wrapper around it ([this project](http://blog.joey-dumont.ca/2012/09/bessel-functions-of-complex-argument.html) appears to have done that so it might be useful – there are others out there too).

You may also be able to use Matlab's Coder and [`codegen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ref/codegen.html) to output something as well.

Comment: `gsl_sf_bessel_Knu_scaled` is working correctly except for first parameter is negative. When first parameter is negative, I get an error as follow: `gsl: bessel_Knu.c:42: ERROR: domain error
Default GSL error handler invoked.
Aborted (core dumped)`. Also, I put this line for error handling `gsl_set_error_handler_off();`, but this time the output of `gsl_sf_bessel_Knu_scaled` is again `nan`. How can I handle this?

Comment: I found that if first parameter is negative, result will be the same with `gsl_sf_bessel_Knu_scaled(abs(firstparam),y)`. So it works. Thank you very much!