# Segment fault when using Rcpp/Armadillo and openMP prarallel with user-defined function

Tags: r, openmp, rcpp

I was trying to use rcpp/armadillo with openmp to speed up a loop in R. The loop takes a matrix with each row containing indices of a location vector(or matrix if it's 2D locations) as input(and other matrix/vec to be used). Inside the loop, I extracted each row of input indices matrix and find the corresponding locations, calculate distance matrix, and covariance matrix, do cholesky and backsolve, save the backsolve results to a new matrix. Here is the rcpp code:

```
`#include <iostream>
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;
using namespace std;

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
mat NZentries_new2 (int m, int nnp, const mat& locs, const umat& revNNarray, const mat& revCondOnLatent, const vec& nuggets, const vec covparms){
// initialized the output matrix
mat Lentries=zeros(nnp,m+1);
// initialized objects in parallel part
int n0; //number of !is_na elements
uvec inds;//
vec revCon_row;//
uvec inds00;//
vec nug;//
mat covmat;//
vec onevec;//
vec M;//
mat dist;//
int k;//
omp_set_num_threads(2);// selects the number of cores to use.
#pragma omp parallel for shared(locs,revNNarray,revCondOnLatent,nuggets,nnp,m,Lentries) private(k,M,dist,onevec,covmat,nug,n0,inds,revCon_row,inds00) default(none) schedule(static)
for (k = 0; k < nnp; k++) {
// extract a row to work with
inds=revNNarray.row(k).t();
revCon_row=revCondOnLatent.row(k).t();

if (k < m){
  n0=k+1;
} else {
  n0=m+1;
}
// extract locations
inds00=inds(span(m+1-n0,m))-ones<uvec>(n0);

nug=nuggets.elem(inds00) % (ones(n0)-revCon_row(span(m+1-n0,m))); // vec is vec, cannot convert to mat
dist=calcPWD2(locs.rows(inds00));

#pragma omp critical
{
  //calculate covariance matrix
  covmat= MaternFun(dist,covparms) + diagmat(nug) ; // summation from arma
}

// get last row of inverse Cholesky
onevec = zeros(n0);
onevec[n0-1] = 1;
M=solve(chol(covmat,"upper"),onevec);
// save the entries to matrix
Lentries(k,span(0,n0-1)) = M.t();
}
return Lentries;
}`
```

The current version works fine but speed is slow(almost the same as no parallel version), if I take the line in omp critical bracket out, it cause segment fault and R will be crashed. This MaterFun is a function I defined as below with several other small functions. So my question is that why MaternFun has to stay in the critical part.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
    mat MaternFun( mat distmat, vec covparms ){

      int d1 = distmat.n_rows;
      int d2 = distmat.n_cols;
      int j1;
      int j2;
      mat covmat(d1,d2);
      double scaledist;

      double normcon = covparms(0)/(pow(2.0,covparms(2)-1)*Rf_gammafn(covparms(2)));

      for (j1 = 0; j1 < d1; j1++){
        for (j2 = 0; j2 < d2; j2++){
          if ( distmat(j1,j2) == 0 ){
            covmat(j1,j2) = covparms(0);
          } else {
            scaledist = distmat(j1,j2)/covparms(1);
            covmat(j1,j2) = normcon*pow( scaledist, covparms(2) )*
              Rf_bessel_k(scaledist,covparms(2),1.0);
          }
        }
      }
      return covmat;
    }

    // [[Rcpp::export]]
    double dist2(double lat1,double long1,double lat2,double long2) {
      double dist = sqrt(pow(lat1 - lat2, 2) + pow(long1 - long2, 2)) ;
      return (dist) ;
    }
   // [[Rcpp::export]]
    mat calcPWD2( mat x) {//Rcpp::NumericMatrix
      int outrows = x.n_rows ;

      int outcols = x.n_rows ;
      mat out(outrows, outcols) ;
      for (int arow = 0 ; arow < outrows ; arow++) {
        for (int acol = 0 ; acol < outcols ; acol++) {
          out(arow, acol) = dist2(x(arow, 0),x(arow, 1),
                                  x(acol, 0),x(acol, 1)) ; //extract element from mat 
        }
      }
      return (out) ;
    }
```

Here is some sample inputs for testing the `MaterFun` in R:
    `library(fields)
    distmat=rdist(1:5) # distance matrix
    covparms=c(1,0.2,1.5)`

Comment: R needs some special care when using OpenMP, in particular the parallel chunks cannot interfere with the underlying R session.   You really need to ensure you satisfy these requirements.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! but I didn't really understand about 'interfere with R session'. Can you explain a little bit?

Comment: Please see eg the _Writing R Extensions_ manual for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is there are two calls to *R* math functions (`Rf_bessel_k` and `Rf_gammafn`) that require the access to be single threaded instead of parallel.

To get around this, let's add a dependency on `boost` via [`BH`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=BH) to obtain the [`cyl_bessel_k`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/bessel/mbessel.html) and [`tgamma`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/sf_gamma/tgamma.html) functions. Alternatively, there is always the option of reimplementing *R*'s [`besselK`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Bessel.html) and [`gamma`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Special.html) in *C++* so it doesn't use the single-threaded *R* variant.

This gives:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <boost/math/special_functions/bessel.hpp>
#include <boost/math/special_functions/gamma.hpp>

// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double besselK_boost(double x, double v) {
  return boost::math::cyl_bessel_k(v, x);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double gamma_fn_boost(double x) {
  return boost::math::tgamma(x);
}
```

Test Code

```
x0 = 9.536743e-07
nu = -10
all.equal(besselK(x0, nu), besselK_boost(x0, nu))
# [1] TRUE

x = 2
all.equal(gamma(x), gamma_fn_boost(x))
# [1] TRUE
```

Note: The order of parameters for boost's variant differs from *R*'s:

```
cyl_bessel_k(v, x)
Rf_bessel_k(x, v, expon.scaled = FALSE)
```

From here, we can modify the `MaternFun`. Unfortunately, because `calcPWD2` is missing, the furthest we can go is switching to use boost and incorporating in [OpenMP protections](http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/openmp-in-r-on-os-x/#protect-your-users).

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <boost/math/special_functions/bessel.hpp>
#include <boost/math/special_functions/gamma.hpp>

#ifdef _OPENMP
#include <omp.h>
#endif

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat MaternFun(arma::mat distmat, arma::vec covparms) {

  int d1 = distmat.n_rows;
  int d2 = distmat.n_cols;
  int j1;
  int j2;
  arma::mat covmat(d1,d2);
  double scaledist;

  double normcon = covparms(0) /
    (pow(2.0, covparms(2) - 1) * boost::math::tgamma(covparms(2)));

  for (j1 = 0; j1 < d1; ++j1){
    for (j2 = 0; j2 < d2; ++j2){
      if ( distmat(j1, j2) == 0 ){
        covmat(j1, j2) = covparms(0);
      } else {
        scaledist = distmat(j1, j2)/covparms(1);
        covmat(j1, j2) = normcon * pow( scaledist, covparms(2) ) *
          boost::math::cyl_bessel_k(covparms(2), scaledist);
      }
    }
  }
  return covmat;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the answer! I will test it out and give feedback on it.

Comment: I applied the `boost` but compiling `MaternFun` gives error: `  'double' is not a class, struct, or union type.` I updated the question all the small functions involved in `MaternFun`

Comment: @Wendy please modify your question with the additional code.

Comment: Sure, I just updated it. I'm a newbie in stack-overflow ... Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Wendy: Could you also add some "sample" inputs or test data?

Comment: So, the issue here is `boost::math::cyl_bessel_k` is generating values that are not matching exactly `Rf_bessel_k(x, v, 1.0)` for certain values of `x` and `y`. So, this probably isn't the best approach to use this function. Instead, you will likely need to implement a clean version of `bessel_k`.  c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615876/what-is-the-exact-equivalent-of-matlab-besselkx-y-1-in-c , https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/af7f52f70101960861e5d995d3a4bec010bc89e6/src/nmath/bessel_k.c , http://octave.org/doxygen/4.0/d8/d3a/cbesk_8f_source.html ,

Comment: The previous error I mentioned is fixed by remove the accidental argument `1.0`. Then I found there is an inconsistency in the order of arguments when define `besselK_boost` function. Once changed it to `boost::math::cyl_bessel_k(x,v);`, the output of `MaterFun` matched, at least for several  different `covparms ` settings.

Comment: Ahh, nice catch @Wendy.